# passing parameter to crystal report asks for parameter value

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, parameter-passing

I have a crystal report in which I am trying to pass label's text to crystal report. But whenever I try to do it asks or parameter value. I have another form in which done same thing but it works fine. Heres my code that I have tried :

```
 crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
            ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
            ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            paramField = new ParameterField();
            paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            paramField.Name = "kot";
            paramDiscreteValue.Value = NewOrderBL.KOTNo;
            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
            paramFields.Add(paramField);

            paramField = new ParameterField();
            paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            paramField.Name = "TotalVat";
            paramDiscreteValue.Value = NewOrderBL.totalvat;
            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
            paramFields.Add(paramField);

            paramField = new ParameterField();
            paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            paramField.Name = "TotalService";
            paramDiscreteValue.Value = NewOrderBL.totalservicetax;
            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
            paramFields.Add(paramField);



            paramField = new ParameterField();
            paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            paramField.Name = "TotalAmount";
            paramDiscreteValue.Value = NewOrderBL.totalamount;
            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
            paramFields.Add(paramField);


            paramField = new ParameterField();
            paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            paramField.Name = "TotalServiceTax";
            paramDiscreteValue.Value = NewOrderBL.totalservicetax1;
            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
            paramFields.Add(paramField);
```

NewOrderBL is a class file where I have defined above variables as 
public static decimal (variable name)

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you doing next with ParameterFields? It does not appear from the code that you have actually added any parameters / values to the report document itself.

**ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();**

Option A:
    Set paramFields to the ParameterFields property of the report document.

Option B: 
    Perhaps look into using ReportDocument.SetParameterValue
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691465%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed it . It was silly left out just added

```
crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
```

below the whole and it works fine.